# How to restrict the generic type to NOT extending a class?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

These are simple methods for creating "delegates" in Java:

```
public static <B> Runnable runnableOf(B o, String methodName) {
    return findMethod(methodName, o.getClass(), o);
}
public static <B> Runnable runnableOf(Class<B> base, String methodName) {
    return findMethod(methodName, base, null);
}
```

There are two cases in this code: when `B` (the class for the method to call) is not `Class<?>`,  the user shall pass an instance of `B` and thus the method will be an instance method. Otherwise, the user can pass a `Class<B>` to call a static method.

However, the compiler complains that they are ambiguous. I think one of the solution is to force `B` in the first overload NOT to be an instance of `Class<?>`. How can I do so?

**UPDATE**

The solution of the above code is given in my own answer. However it is not answering the question in title. I hope anybody can answer it and give another examples that makes sense.

Comment: What is your compiler version. Eclipse-Compiler doesnt complain

Comment: Java 6 SE and Eclipse JDT compiler both don't complain

Comment: No compilation errors seen. Can you try  by deleteing old .class filed and then creating new .class files.

Comment: The ambiguous is in `findMethod`, not `runnableOf`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that's a mistake. The problem is that `findMethod` do not know what is the type of `null`. So the fix is the following:

```
public static <B> Runnable runnableOf(Class<B> base, String methodName) {
    return findMethod(methodName, base, (B)null);
}
```

I don't know weather or not people can do what I described in the title, however in my example it is NOT necessory.